# Myro - Moving robot in a circle based on the radius a user inputs

Tags: python, geometry, radius, myro

I'm using a Scribbler robot.

There doesn't seem to be a function in the Myro library that has the robot move in a circle at a user specified radius.

Here's what I was able to gather

The distance between the left and right wheel of the robot is 6 inches.

So the left wheel should travel at a distance of 2(pi)(radius+6)

And the right wheel should travel at a distance of 2(pi) (radius-6)

(I think)

Moving the robot in a circle is rather simple.  I could just use the `motors` function and call

```
motors(1, 0)
```

Meaning the left wheel moves, and the right wheel stops, effectively moving in a circle.

My issue is specifying a radius for the circle and getting it to move in a circle of that radius.

Here's a code I have.

```
    #Practice for Circle
def goCircle(int radius):
    pi = 3.14159265359
    Left = 2(pi)(radius + 6)
    Right = 2(pi)(radius - 6)
    turnRight(1,radius/360.0)
```

generally `turnRight` would have these parameters `turnRight(speed, time)`  So you specify the speed you'd like the robot to go, and the seconds you'd like it to travel.   I put it at 1 speed, and tried passing the radius/360 in the time variable.

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in goCircle
TypeError: int is not callable
```

I also tried `motors(left, right)` and got the same error

```
    #Practice for Circle
def goCircle(radius):
    pi = 3.14159265359
    Left = 2(pi)(radius + 6)
    Right = 2(pi)(radius - 6)

    motors(left,right)
```

What could I do to make this work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2*(pi)*(radius + 3) and 2*(pi)*(radius - 3) assuming you want the radius of the circle to end at the center of the robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you of your syntax. You cannot multiply with:

`2(pi)(radius + 6)`

You need to put `*` between the terms:

`2*(pi)*(radius + 6)`

The interpreter thinks that you are tying to call an int like a function `2()`.

Also, if you `import math`, you get math.pi built in.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out an easier way to do it.  But that may have been my problem, I may have forgot to import math.  And I should have did * between 2 and (pi).